# Excel 2007 floating format toolbar customisation

Tags: formatting, excel-2007, toolbar

Is it possible in Excel 2007 to customise the floating format bar that is shown when you right-click on a cell? To avoid confusion, I don't mean the "Cell" commandbar menu, but the second floating toolbar with formatting buttons.

e.g. is it possible to add a Styles dropdown, or have any other text alignment option than centre?

Thanks in advance,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, [the Office 2007 mini toolbar cannot be customised](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-formatting-to-your-document-by-using-the-mini-toolbar-HA010173624.aspx).